# Slider with one handle - Updating two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I am using [noUISlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) Library to create a slider with one handle going up or down and updating two different values.

This is javascript I am using:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

var lastValue = 50;

var counter1 = 1.0;
var counter2 = 100;

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: 50,
    step: 2,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(){

    //Increase
    if (slider.noUiSlider.get() > lastValue){
    counter1 = counter1 + 0.10;
    counter2 = counter2 - 1;
    $(".counter1").html(counter1.toFixed(1));
    $(".counter2").html(counter2.toFixed(0));
  }

  //decrease
  if (slider.noUiSlider.get() < lastValue){
    counter1 = counter1 - 0.10;
    counter2 = counter2 + 1;

    $(".counter1").html(counter1.toFixed(1));
    $(".counter2").html(counter2.toFixed(0));
  }

  lastValue = slider.noUiSlider.get();;
});
```

Since the values are totally different, I want that when the slider gets to the very left (i.e start) the counter1 becomes 0 and counter 2 becomes 200 for example.

If the slider is moved to the far right (i.e end) counter1 becomes 2.0 and counter2 becomes 0.

Counter1 steps are 0.10 and counter2 steps are 1.

My solution is giving me negative numbers and I cannot get to my final numbers.

I have also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxs38wa3/) on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben West is correct that you're adding values based on slider movement without taking into account how far it's moved.  So you only need to keep track of the slider position and calculate your values for apples and oranges from that.  Here's the code you need and the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hbcgdv4q/

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: 100,
    step: 2,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 200
    }
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(){

  var counter1;
  var counter2;
  var sliderGet;
  sliderGet = slider.noUiSlider.get();

  counter1 = sliderGet/100;
  counter2 = 200 - sliderGet;

  $(".counter1").html(counter1.toFixed(1));
  $(".counter2").html(counter2.toFixed(0));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only adding to your variables based on the fact the slider has moved, but not how far it's moved. In other words, if I move the slider fast, your function gets called a few times, if I move it slowly it gets called a lot of times.

When the slider's at the left its value (`slider.noUiSlider.get()`) is 0, when it's at the right it's 100. You want your first counter to go from 0 to 2, so that's just `slider.noUiSlider.get() / 50`. See if you can work out the second one - you don't need to store `counter1`, `counter2` or `lastValue`, the slider value is all you need.

Comment: I don't think you understood my issue, counter 1 and counter 2 work differently, if counter 1 increase then 2 decrease and vice versa. they both behave with a different step value and their final value is also different. one is a max of 2.0 whereas the other is a max of 200

Comment: Does `slider.noUiSlider.get() / 50` give the right value for counter 1? Ignoring the step for now.

Comment: Yes, that does give me the correct value start or end. How to get to the other calculation is the problem

Comment: It seems impossible to get to the other calculation of counter 2 and I would still need to identify if the slider is going left or right cause of addition or subtraction